# Calculation of a Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}(4-z^2)^{-1/2}dz
\end{align}
$$

The exercise hints at the usage of $e^{2Logz}$ , although any solution or methodology for such integrals would be welcome.

Comment: Hint: what is the contour integral of a function $f$ over the unit circle when $f$ is analytic over the unit disk?

Comment: this should be $0$ I think,but is this that simple?

Comment: Yes, it is that simple. What you need to do is justify $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-z^2}}$ is analytic over the unit disk.

Comment: You should know in what region the integrand is analytic.

Comment: Is the fact that the denomitator $\neq 0$ sufficient in general, or do I have to prove it in a more explicit way? Either way , thanks for your answer.

Comment: In general, if a function $f$ is analytic over a [simply connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) domain $\mathcal{D}$, then $f \ne 0$ over $\mathcal{D}$ is sufficient to force $\sqrt{f}$ analytic over $\mathcal{D}$. For this particular case, you can arrive the same conclusion by a different route. The integrand has two singularity $\pm 2$ and there is a branch cut starting from each of them. You are free to choose the branch cut at long as they end at $\pm 2$. It is clear you can deform the branch cut not to intersect the unit disk, so your $f$ is analytic there.

Comment: @helplessKirk: I already pointed out for you what helps you to solve the problem in my previous comment.

Comment: @achillehui , Thank you very much , your comment was helpful not only for this specific case , but gave me a better view in general. I posted the previous comment asking if it is sufficient before I got to read yours last comment.

Comment: @helplessKirk: You are very welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your function has no poles inside the region of integration.

See this post for a general discussion: 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica

Comment: thanks for the link , I'm not that familiar with mathematica though. I'm reading it now.